# manage and remove objectId from array - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

i have this schema structure

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "571251dae4b065a8c4d70ce1"
},
"email": "somthing12345@gmail.com",
"events": [
    {
        "$oid": "57125378e4b065a8c4d70d10"
    },
    {
        "$oid": "571253b8e4b065a8c4d70d1b"
    }
],
"valid": true,
```

}

and my problem is this part

```
"events": [
{
    "$oid": "57125378e4b065a8c4d70d10"
},
{
    "$oid": "571253b8e4b065a8c4d70d1b"
}
```

]

how to remove object in this structure?

can i add fields to each one of thos "events" objects like-

"title" : "some string".

how should i add this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For removing:

```
events.update({
    _id: "571251dae4b065a8c4d70ce1"
  }, {
    $pull: {
      events: {
        $oid: "57125378e4b065a8c4d70d10"
      }
    }
  }, {
    safe: true
  }, function(err, obj) {
    // code goes here
  });
```

And what about adding field title: "some string", mondoDB at this moment doesn't allow multiple update for embedded documents, so the only one way to achieve your goal is select document from db, then take this document events array and add title to each object of array. save whole document whith changed events array. Hope you understand everything :)

Comment: thanks for you replay and time. i will try that and update here if anything goes wrong.