# Check if a property exists inside an array - mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

how can I check if an id exists inside an array of id-like strings?

```
Item.deleteMany({"id": array_of_ids).then(()=>{})
```

the array looks something like this:

```
[
  '613320286d245f45683830d9',
  '61332039d5e4192f409fda33',
  '61332046d5e4192f409fda50',
  '613321f71203f944cc34683b',
  '6133226f04aaf64920178e4d'
]
```

Comment: You can use [find]() to find element in an array.

Comment: if you want to remove objectId from the array use `$pull` like this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37634613/5911891   .if you want to find an Id inside array of Ids you can use `$in` like https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/mongoose+find+id+in+array+of+ids . also `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` is for casting string to objectId.

Comment: @SoroushSalehi404 Thanks! the second link was exactly what I was looking for!